# Redirect login page to another page in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, authentication

I am doing a admin panel for my website.I used PrimeFaces login form for admin.I can log in and see messages.But I want to redirect page to another page after admin is logged in. I couldn't do this.How can I do?

```
<h:form>
    <p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true" life="3000" />

    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" />
        <p:inputText id="username" value="#{userLoginView.username}" required="true" label="username" />
        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
        <p:password id="password" value="#{userLoginView.password}" required="true" label="password" />

        <h:column>
            <p:commandButton value="Login"
                             update="growl"
                             actionListener="#{userLoginView.login}"
                             oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args)" />
        </h:column>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

```
@ManagedBean
public class UserLoginView {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void login(ActionEvent event) {
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        FacesMessage message = null;
        boolean loggedIn = false;

        if (username != null && username.equals("admin") && password != null && password.equals("admin")) {
            loggedIn = true;
            message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Welcome", username);
        } else {
            loggedIn = false;
            message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Loggin Error", "Invalid credentials");
        }

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        context.addCallbackParam("loggedIn", loggedIn);
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of JSF are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply give the method a redirection action :

In Managed Bean, in the login method :

```
if (username != null && username.equals("admin") && password != null && password.equals("admin")) {
    loggedIn = true;
    message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Welcome", username);
// Edit :
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.getExternalContext().redirect("/newfodler/newindex.xhtml");
```

**Unrelated :** To show messages of the result (like Welcome username) in the new redirected page, you should use :

```
    context.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
```

That way messages aren't lost on the transaction between pages.

Comment: @Chaibi Alaa answer explains the programmatically option to make a redirection. In simple scenarios I'll go for the solution shown in my answer.

Comment: I added  context.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true); But I can not show messages

Comment: Can you verify the id of the messages component and that the bean is posting messages in the correct id ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `action` attribute instead `actionListener` attribute and just return the navigation information in the action method.

For example:

```
return "theApplicationPage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
```

You should make your backing bean view scoped (JSF 2.2 for CDI compatibility). You can write:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class UserLoginView  implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can't comment I am almost responding to lametaweb message.

You can use action attribute instead actionListener attribute and just return the navigation information in the action method.

For example:

```
return "theApplicationPage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
```

Instead, I would return a string "theApplicationPage"

```
return "theApplicationPage";
```

and create a navigation rule in faces-config.xml:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>login.xhtml</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/jsp/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>theApplicationPage</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/jsp/menu.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

I would make the backing bean session scoped, you probably will use it later to render or to add more functionality to your website. Just add
@SessionScoped

Right after your @ManagedBean.

Comment: no. First it's not a message, it's an answer. Second, in all technical disciplines there is a very important actor: Best practices. You must leran and apply them from the beginning. So, in general, for Ajax pages, view scope from the beginning. Related to navigation I prefer implicit navigation, introduced in JSF 2.0. It's clear, efficient and easy to manage.